# how to properly check if a given url do a download of a file?

Tags: python, http, http-headers

I already tried check the content-type, but the server can "fake" this, and return a text/html instead of application/octet-stream and even so do the download, and the content-disposition is not part of http standard so won't work for all cases. any suggestion?

e.g.:https://get.adobe.com/br/reader/download/?installer=Reader_DC_2015.009.20069_English_for_Windows&os=Windows%207&browser_type=KHTML&browser_dist=Chrome&d=McAfee_Security_Scan_Plus_Chrome_Browser&dualoffer=false&chromedefault=false

Comment: What do you mean by "content-disposition is not part of http standard"? If you're looking at RFC 2616: don't. It's obsolete.

Comment: @Julian Reschke The implementation of content-disposition isn't mandatory so may I have this information or not.

Comment: At this point I'm not sure what your question is. A URI doesn't "do" anything. You access the URI using HTTP GET, and get a response. That response can declare itself  to be an attachment (using Content-Disposition), or it can have a content type the browser doesn't know about and thus offers to download.

Otherwise, it might be HTML + JS, in which case the JS of course can trigger lots of subsequent actions that have little to do with the response header fields of the initial response.

Comment: @JulianReschke I got you, so how can I check if this JS will download a file just analyzing the response?